# Adding a SubElement to the text of a parent Element in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML (XLIFF) file that has tags like `<source>Lorem ipsum ^NAME sit amet dolor [[COLOR]]</source>`. I need a way to introduce `<ph>` tags around the `^NAME` and `[[COLOR]]` markers in the text of the `<source>` tag.

My first idea was:

1. Use regular expressions to get Python [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) objects for each place that one of these patterns is found.
2. Remove the match from the text, and use the [`Element.insert()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.insert) function of Python to insert a new `<ph>` element at that point.

The problem has been that any `<ph>` elements that I create end up at the very end of the `<source>` tag.

Input: `<source>Lorem ipsum ^NAME sit amet dolor [[COLOR]]</source>`

Actual output: `<source>Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor <ph>^NAME</ph><ph>[[COLOR]]</ph></source>`

I made a workaround by writing the XML file as-is, then reading it back and manually adding in the  tags without the use of ElementTree. I would like to find a way to do this before writing the XML file, using ElementTree. Any help?

Comment: I was going to suggest substitutions using regular expressions on the XML treated as plain text instead of manipulating the parsed tree. Is that what you mean by "manually adding in the tags"? What is the problem with the workaround if it gets the work done?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by manually adding them in. Workaround is fine, just wanted to see if there was a more "native" way to do it that didn't require manually reading! But it seems there might not be.

Comment: You want to change an element's content from text-only to mixed content. I think it is possible to do this the "native" way with some clever string-splitting and by using the `tail` and `text` properties on `Element` objects. But it seems a lot easier to simply do substitutions on the XML as plain text.